# Accessing properties of the DOM element corresponding to a view, after DOM update is completed

Tags: ember.js

This is what I am [trying](http://jsbin.com/ovaWUbU/1):

1. Preview of an image selected with `FileReader`, using an ember view.
2. Get information about the selected image (`naturalWidth`). For this what I am doing is getting the related DOM element using jQuery and the ember `elementId`

(I do not know if there is a better way to get the related DOM element, or even better, to directly access the properties of the DOM element from the view object, without even accessing the DOM at all)

The main problem I have is that whenever the `src` attribute of the `img` element is updated (because a new file has been selected), the element attributes are not immediately available. The values are just the ones that were set before the data was loaded. On first selection:

```
width=100 height=0 naturalWidth=0 naturalHeight=0
```

(On successive selections, the parameters from the old image are found)

I guess it takes some time for the DOM element to process the new data in the `src` attribute. How can I trigger an action whenever the DOM has completed updating the element?

(This is not about creation of the element, since it is already there, but about update completion)

Answer (score 0):

i think you can use `didInsertElement` :

```
App.PreviewUploadImage = Ember.ContainerView.extend({
didInsertElement:function(){
console.log(this.$().find('img'));
},
```

Comment: Thanks, but according to my testing, `didInsertElement` is fired when the element is inserted for the first time, not when it is updated.

Comment: so how about using attribute bindings ? create a computed porperty with src of image property then each time src changed you know.